# Qpython3, sqlite3 can't connect to database

Tags: sqlite, qpython3

I'm beginner and I just try qpython for android.

I try to connect database at qpython3 by using sqlite3:
My code

```
import sqlite3
conn=sqlite3.connect('mydatabase.db')
```

But it raises error and unable to open database file.

Any solution for this??
If I try at pc, it automatically create a database if not exists

Comment: haven't ever used neither android, nor qpython but you might want to check if your script has correct permissions to write to that folder.

Answer (score 1):

The reason it doesn't work is that QPython programs are run from '/' directory which of course is not writable to non-root users.  You can check this with the following code run from the console.

```
import os
print(os.getcwd())
```

If you go to the `ftp` utility in the About menu, you will find a directory path that is being used by QPython3. On my HTC mobile it is:

```
/storage/emulated/0/com.hipipal.qpyplus
```

So I changed your example code to:

```
import os
import sqlite3
RootPath='/storage/emulated/0/com.hipipal.qpyplus'
conn=sqlite3.connect(os.path.join(RootPath,'mydatabase.db'))
```

and it works fine for me.

I also found that it is necessary to commit changes or they won't be written to the file. That is, end programs with:

```
conn.commit()
conn.close()
```